# Enter path (as argument) to files that are processed by python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

i need a help!

I have some logs from which is needed to parse/extract some informations. These logs are for different cases and saved in different folders. I made some python script that extract the info's i need but what i want is to be able to give the location of folder/files as argument in script so that i don't need to copy and execute the .py script every time to another folder. The part of code looks like this, ignore all these initialized var's:

```
def peip(*args):

    split_data = ''
    split_data1 = ''
    split_data2 = ''
    split_data3 = ''
    split_data4 = ''
    split_data5 = ''
    split_data6 = ''
    split_data7 = ''
    split_data8 = ''
    split_data9 = ''
    split_data10 = ''
    split_data11 = ''
    SPU = ''
    Burst = ''
    CountRTT_avrg = 0
    output = []
    Mbps = []
    Total_Packets1 = []

    output.append('Peip1 Pack., Peip2 Pack., Peip3 Pack., Peip4 Pack., Total Packets, Mbps, SPU Load(%), Average RTT(ms), Burst\n')
    for arg in args:
        print "another arg:", arg
        if arg == 'putty_1_1.log':
            with open ('putty_1_1' + '.log', mode='r') as a:
                lines = a.readlines() #lines is list
                for i, line in enumerate(lines):
                    if line.startswith('^C--'):
                        data = lines[i - 1].strip()
                        split_data = data.split()[4]
                        split_data1 = data.split()[6]
                print 'PeipX Mbps:', split_data
                print 'PeipX packets:', split_data1

        elif arg == 'putty_1_2_rtt.log': 
            with open ('putty_1_2_rtt' + '.log', mode='r') as b:
                lines1 = b.readlines() #lines is list
                for i, line in enumerate(lines1):
                    if line.startswith('rtt'):
                        data = lines1[i].strip()
                split_data2 = data.split('/')[4]
                print 'avg rtt/peipX:', split_data2
# ...
# ...
# ...
# and at the end i have calling the function...

names = []
Num_of_input_logs = raw_input('Enter the number of input logs: ')
#print Num_of_input_logs
for z in range(0, int(Num_of_input_logs)):
    Input_logs = raw_input('Enter the input logs one by one: ')
    names.append(Input_logs)
    print names
    print z

peip(*names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might just want to use arguments and argparse instead of interactive input.

```
import argparse
import os

def peip(filenames):
    for filename in filenames:
        realname = os.path.realpath(filename)
        basename = os.path.basename(filename)  # to get the filename only
        print(filename, basename, realname)
        with open(realname) as f:
            if basename == 'something.log':
                pass  # do things!



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    ap.add_argument('files', metavar='file', nargs='*')
    args = ap.parse_args()
    if not args.files:
        ap.error('no files!')
    peip(args.files)
```

And a random example...

```
$ python3 so51282670.py  ../Pictures/*.jpg
../Pictures/citd.jpg citd.jpg /Users/akx/Pictures/citd.jpg
../Pictures/citd2.jpg citd2.jpg /Users/akx/Pictures/citd2.jpg
../Pictures/Goodboy.jpg Goodboy.jpg /Users/akx/Pictures/Goodboy.jpg
../Pictures/Prairie.jpg Prairie.jpg /Users/akx/Pictures/Prairie.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your suggestion with this approach but I'm not so experienced to be able to completely understand what you have done with your code. I would be more satisfied if my code could be adjusted to get what i asked for.

Comment: Sorry if this sounds blunt, but I'm sure that in the slightly longer run you'll be more satisfied with my idea here. With your input-based approach, you'll be spending a whole lot of time typing/copy-pasting in numbers and filenames. What parts of the code do you not understand?